# Can we disable subTabs completely in a Lightning Console App?

Tags: lightning, console

10,000 ft view of the problem? When in a Lightning Console App, I ALWAYS, UNCONDITIONALLY want to open links to Products in a Workspace Tab. I NEVER want Products to open as a SubTab.

20,000 ft view of the problem ? I don't want ANYTHING to ever open in a SubTab. I don't care what kind of 'thing' I am viewing, if I click on a link (ANYWHERE) to view that object, I want it to be displayed as a Workspace Tab. Got it ? :)

Let's just talk about the first scenario (with the Product object).
We have setup Products as a Navigation Item in the App. Great!
The behavior observed when clicking on a Product Link from the Navigation Item is directly influenced by the Navigation Rules for the App (Setup -> App Manager -> Edit -> Navigation Rules). 
So we say that we want to open Products as a Workspace Tab and it all works) Great.
If I'm currently viewing the Record Page of a product (that has been opened in a Workspace Tab) and I click on a 'Product' link (within the Lightning Record Page for the Product) it opens as a SubTab of the current Workspace Tab. Uhmmm?? I don't want that to happen. 
**I want ALL links to Products to open as a Workspace Tab, whether the link was from a List in the Products Navigation Item tab at the top, or from a link anywhere else.**

So, my poor brain struggles with this 'Navigation Rule' that says 'Always open Products as a Workspace Tab', as that really isn't true right?

Am I misreading this, or is the functionality busted, or is it simply poorly written and it's behaving as designed, or am I an idiot :) ?

At the 20,000ft level, ***for links to objects that don't even have a Navigation Item in the menu, well, it appears I have no choice about the behavior***. It opens as a SubTab inside the workspace tab in which the link was clicked. I don't want that. Same deal as the product, I simply want EVERYTHING to open as a Workspace Tab.

I really don't want to hear about Aura Wrappers, and workspaceAPI and hidden Utility Bar widgets with custom messaging logic blah blah. Yes, this may be a solution I 'could' use for links we create on our our LWC components (that live on a Lightning Record Page), but **I have NO control of what happens when a normal salesfore generated link (say from a related list, or wherever actually) is clicked, and that is my problem.** 
so....

**Is there a big red switch that I can flick that turns of ALL Subtab functionality?**
I think I know the answer, but thought I'd ask anyway ....

Thanks

ps. All this hoop jumping is to try any control/determine the amount of vertical space I have available for my LWC when it sits on the Lightning Record Page of a Product. (but that is digressing......)